# How to combine the data in 2 columns without removing the empty cells in between the columns in google sheet?

Tags: jquery, google-sheets

[image]

Hi everyone,

I want to combine column B and column D in column F. The formula that I used in column F is:

`=query({B2:B1000;D2:D1000}, "select * where Col1 is not null ")`

I used `where Col1 is not null` in the `Query` because I want to avoid the empty cells start from cell `B14` onwards. However, it removed the empty cell in between column B (cell `B7` & `B8`) as well. May I know how should I modified my query function so that it includes the empty cells in between column B and column D.
The desired output should be like this:
[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use closed ranges in the formula:

```
={B2:B13; D2:D6}
```

or, if you want to use open ranges, try something like

```
={INDIRECT("B2:B"&max(FILTER(row(B2:B), len(B2:B)))); INDIRECT("D2:D"&max(FILTER(row(D2:D), len(D2:D))))}
```

and see if that works?